# My divs are overlapping and I don't know what to do

Tags: html, css

Two of my `<div>` elements are overlapping and don't display properly. I've tried everything I can think of and they still overlap. Can anyone help me? The `div` elements in question are the two `card` divs inside the `body` div. The two divs overlap right on top of each other when displayed in a web browser. Thanks!

Files:

lineCard.css:

```
    /* Styling for the title of the page */
.title {
    color: #666666; /* the color of the title (dark gray) */
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Arial', sans-serif; /* the font of the title */
    font-size: 36px; /* the font size of the title */
    font-weight: bold; /* make the font bold */
    line-height: 44px; /* the spacing between lines */
    text-align: left; /* align the title on the left side of the page */
}

/* Styling for the subtitle of the page */
.subtitle {
    height: 27px; /* the height of the subtitle */
    left: 255px; /* the left margin of the subtitle */
    position: absolute; /* absolute positioning */
    top: 73px; /* the top margin of the subtitle */
    width: 318px; /* the width of the subtitle */
    color: #7BBD2F; /* the color of the subtitle (green) */
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Bold', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; /* the font of the subtitle */
    font-size: 22px; /* the font size of the title */
    line-height: 27px; /* 27 pixels between lines */
    font-weight: bold; /* make the font bold */
    padding-bottom: 10px; /* 10 pixels of padding on the bottom */
    text-align: left; /* align the text on the right */
}

/* Styling for the logo */
.logo {
    float: left; /* move to the left side of the page */
    width: 217px; /* the exact width of the logo - CHANGE THIS IF LOGO WIDTH CHANGES */
    height: 391px; /* the exact height of the logo - CHANGE THIS IF LOGO HEIGHT CHANGES */
    border: 10px solid #999999; /* surround with a 10-pixel gray border */
    padding: 13px; /* allow for 13 pixels of padding around the logo */
}

/* Styling for the different cards */
.card {
    display: block; /* block display */
    overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow */
    float: left; /* move to the left side of the page */
    left: 300px; /* minimum of 300 pixels from the left side of the page */
    font-size: 10px; /* make the font smaller */
    position: absolute; /* absolute positioning */
    border: 10px solid #999999; /* surround with a 10-pixel gray border */
    width: 475px; /* the width of the card */
    height: 300px; /* the height of the card */
    padding: 7px; /* allow for 7 pixels of padding around the card */
}

/* Styling for the card images */
.card img {
    width: 275px; /* make the images have a width of 275 pixels */
    height: 80px; /* make the images have a height of 80 pixels */
    top: 20%; /* top of image is 20% of card */
    bottom: 20%; /* bottom of image is 20% of card */
    left: 20%; /* left of image is 20% of card */
    right: 20%; /* right of image is 20% of card */
}

/* Styling for the body text*/
.body {
    float: left; /* move to the left */
    color: #404040; /* the color of the body (more dark gray)*/
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; /* the font of the body */
    font-size: 12px; /* the size of the body font */
    line-height: 17px; /* 17 pixels between lines */
    font-weight: bold; /* make the font bold */
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: left; /* align the body text to the left */
}

/* Styling for the check boxes */
.body img {
    display: inline-block; /* display the check boxes inline */
    float: left; /* move towards the left */
    position: relative; /* relative positioning */
    top: 1px; /* 1 pixel space at the top */
}
```

lineCard.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Line Card</title> <!--the title that shows in a Web browser's title bar-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/lineCard.css"> <!--import the stylesheet-->
</head>
<body>
    <!--First we define the menu-->
    <div class="menu">
    </div>
    <br>
    <p class="title">redacted</p> <!--display the first line of the title-->
    <p class="subtitle">redacted</p> <!--display the second line of the title-->
    <img class="logo" src="redacted" alt="redacted"> <!--create the logo image-->
    <div class="body">
        <!--now we display the different info cards -->
        <div class="card">
            <!--first we display the logo as a link-->
            <a redacted</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <!--then we display the text of the card-->
            <p>redacted</p>
            <p>redacted</p>
            <p>redacted</p>
            <p>redacted</p>
            <p>redacted</p>
            <p>redacted</p>
            <p>redacted</p>
            <p>redacted</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <!--as always, the logo comes first-->
            <a redacted</a>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <!--then we display the text of the card-->
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `position: absolute` takes the element out of the normal flow and positions it, well, absolutely.

Comment: Take out the `position:absolute;` and then position them using other means.  Did you write the css yourself?

Comment: When you use position absolute too much, you have to be careful and trying to use position relative when you want to position elements absolutely as @ray said.

Answer (score 0):

## Modify your CSS

Hi Techgineer

I have made these modifications to your CSS and the divs no longer overlap, I comment in .card the position and in the .body add a specific width (width:300px [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh0e3.png))

```
enter code here
.card {
    /*display: block;*/ /* block display */
    overflow: hidden; /* hide overflow */
    float: left; /* move to the left side of the page */
    left: 300px; /* minimum of 300 pixels from the left side of the page */
    font-size: 10px; /* make the font smaller */
    /*position: absolute;*/ /* absolute positioning */
    border: 10px solid #999999; /* surround with a 10-pixel gray border */
    width: 475px; /* the width of the card */
    height: 300px; /* the height of the card */
    padding: 7px; /* allow for 7 pixels of padding around the card */
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}

/* Styling for the body text*/
.body {
    float: left; /* move to the left */
    color: #404040; /* the color of the body (more dark gray)*/
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Arial', sans-serif; /* the font of the body */
    font-size: 12px; /* the size of the body font */
    line-height: 17px; /* 17 pixels between lines */
    font-weight: bold; /* make the font bold */
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    text-align: left; /* align the body text to the left */
    width: 300px;
}
```